# Getting control panel user data in javascript

Tags: control-panel

Im working on a simple plugin that just needs to get the current logged users screen name, email address and username into some javascript and inject that js on every page.

My hope is to juse the exiwting CP CSS & JS plugin and past the javascript..

I found the EE global variable in the javascript and it looks like EE.username is the current logged in users name.  Is there similar way to get email and/or screen name?

Answer (score 1):

The EE global only has username and shouldn't be relied upon as it's not a formal documented method to get information (and so could change or be manipulated).

If you're already writing a module/extension (a "plugin" is frontend only), then output your JavaScript from there instead of relying on the "CP CSS & JS" extension.

You can access all the user information via the [session class](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html):

```
ee()->session->userdata['screen_name'];
ee()->session->userdata['email'];
ee()->session->userdata['username'];
```

Add your own external JS file:

```
ee()->add_js_script('file', 'insert filename here');
```

The Docs on the CP class can be found [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/cp.html). Full Developer documentation [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html).

Consider using an [Extension hook](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/javascript/index.html) to inject your javascript - this would probably be the easiest route.

Note: These classes are automatically available from within your module/extension and don't have to be loaded.